# How can I realize a refresh button of DataGrid WPF

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

How can I make a refresh button for mine DB which withdraws to DataGrid? I have this:

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection()
        con.ConnectionString = "server =" + server + ";" + "user id=" + username + ";" + "password= " + password + ";" + "database =" + database
        con.Open()
        'Dim query As String
        'query = "select * from suspects_arrests"

        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()

        cmd.CommandText = "select * from suspects_arrests"
        cmd.Connection = con
        Dim sqlAdap As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("suspects_arrests")
        sqlAdap.Fill(sqlData)
        DataSuspects.ItemsSource = sqlData.DefaultView
        con.Close()
```

But this is duplicating records. DataSuspects.Items.Refresh/Clear not working. On Items.Clear() goes this error:

> The operation is invalid when the ItemsSource is in use. Instead, access and modify items using ItemsControl.ItemsSource

[Not pressed (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBAWP.jpg)

[When pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVIEL.jpg)

Comment: the problem is with the itemsSource not the data grid. datagrids shows only the items from the source not the source and old showed items.

Comment: make sure that your itemsSource already contains exactly what you want to show